# VPS System for Ubuntu?

Tags: server, vps

I run a mid sized hosting service/computer rental shop. I'm looking into starting a VPS Provider Service. Is there a way for me to automate VPS provisioning on ubuntu server? (I.E. A multipass plugin)

Answer (score 1):

[Cloud-init](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CloudInit) is designed to make automated setup of VMs and Containers easy.